# vcpkg: Specify struct member alignment

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vcpkg, struct-member-alignment

I have some old code which is compiled with packing of 1-byte (argument `/Zp1`) [Struct Member Alignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zp-struct-member-alignment?view=vs-2019) and I'm adding unit testing with gTest to them. I'm using `vcpkg` to install gTest, but it is compiled using the default setting of 8-byte packing. I'm on Windows with VS2019.

Is it possible to specify which packing to use (parameter `/Zp`) with `vcpkg`?

Answer (score 0):

As it isn't possible to change the Struct Member Alignment of the libraries with `vcpkg` during compilation: I had to change my code to use different [packing alignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack), when including the headers of these libraries.

Everywhere I use the headers of gTest or other libraries provided by `vcpkg`, I enclosed these with `#pragma pack(push, n)` and `#pragma pack(pop)`. The value of `n` depends on default settings, which in my case is `8`.

```cpp
// project specific headers
#include "version.hxx"

// 3rd party libraries (provided by vcpkg)
#pragma pack(push, 8)
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gtest/gmock.h>
#pragma pack(pop)

// STL
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
```

It's not the best solution, but at least a workaround to use `vcpkg` with code, that uses a different packing alignment.